# About stumpwm and swank(clisp)

Tags: clisp, slimv, stumpwm

I have built stumpwm using thread enabled clisp successfully. And the created stumpwm works great. However, the swank server doesnot work if started from ~/.stumpwmrc as below:

```
(load  "~/.vim/slime/start-swank.lisp")
```

The swank server is indeed started as `netstat -na` shows it is lisening on port 4005. But `telnet 127.0.0.1 4005` will report "connection is closed by peer".  So that the slimv in VIM cannot connect to swank server.

If i start another clisp REPL and run `(load  "~/.vim/slime/start-swank.lisp")`, then both telnet and slimv works ok.

Why doesnot `(load  "~/.vim/slime/start-swank.lisp")` in ~/.stumpwmrc work ?

FYI, The stumpwm log:

```
 Starting swank on port 4005
 ;;  Loading file /home/***/.vim/slime/start-swank.lisp ...
 ;;  Loading file /home/***/.vim/slime/swank-loader.lisp ...
 ;;  Loaded file /home/***/.vim/slime/swank-loader.lisp
 ;;   Loading file /home/***/.slime/fasl/2012-03-06/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/swank-backend.fas ...
 ;;  ...
 ;;   Loaded file /home/***/.slime/fasl/2012-03-06/clisp-2.49-unix-pc386/contrib/swank-mrepl.fas
 ;; Swank started at port: 4005.
```

It seems ok but i cannot use stumpwm anymore !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the clisp mailing list, i got a suggestion: We should modify ~/.vim/slime/swank-clisp as below:

```
(defimplementation preferred-communication-style () :spawn)
```

After running `(load "~/.vim/slime/start-swank.lisp")` to start swank server, the slimv can connect to swank server without any error.

Now slimv works great with clisp(with thread support) .

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with slimv, but it seems that all you're looking to do is start a server in lisp and connect to it. Keep it simple. As I don't really want to find out too much about what's going on in `start-swank.lisp`, and you probably don't either, I would recommend you start a swank server by putting this in your .stumpwmrc:

```
(ql:quickload "swank")
(swank:create-server :port #<choose a port number>)
```

Then connect on that port number with slimv's equivalent of `M-x slime-connect`. If the version of swank in quicklisp is not compatible with slimv, make sure you have one that is, and `REQUIRE` it.

Try it out and, if it still doesn't work, look at the version numbers of swank and slimv and post your findings.

Comment: Swank communication should be available also via telnet. The command `telnet 127.0.0.1 4005` should connect to the swank server, then entering `00002d(:emacs-rex (swank:connection-info) nil t 1)` should make it respond with the actual connection info. If this does not work, then it's a swank server problem. Otherwise if the swank server responds and then immediately closes the connection, then you should pass `:dont-close t` to `swank:create-server` in order to keep the connection open.